# apt-get prompts for CDs when installing packages, how do I make it stop?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt, repository

I used ubuntu linux before, and I installed debian OS on my labtop using DVDs that I burned. But when I'm trying to use apt-get to install software, the system always asks me to insert disk to proceed. I wonder if there is a way to change the repository configuration so that I can retrieve installation files online instead of using disks.

Comment: I just found out that it's the sources.list file that have caused the problem. But after I comment the "deb cdrom" thing, I'm no longer able to get any software update :( Does anyone have a nice sources.list file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Package sources are listed in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Usually you would list official sources in the main file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add third-party repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/indicative_name.list`.

If you installed from CD-ROM, there'll be a line with

```
deb cdrom:[some name]/ stable main
```

Remove it or comment it out (by adding a `#` at the beginning of the line). If you ever want to install from CD-ROM again, pop the CD in and run `apt-cdrom` to create a `sources.list` entry from that CD-ROM.

To install packages over the Internet, you would typically list a Debian mirror as a source. The system installation does this if you have an Internet connection. A typical set of entries look like this:

```
## Debian stable proper
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian squeeze main non-free contrib
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian squeeze main non-free contrib

## Security updates
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

## Other updates to the stable release (formerly volatile)
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian squeeze-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian squeeze-updates main contrib non-free

## Quasi-official backports
deb http://www.backports.org/debian/ squeeze-backports main non-free contrib
deb-src http://www.backports.org/debian/ squeeze-backports main non-free contrib

## Marillat: multimedia support and other less free or stable stuff
deb http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze main
deb-src http://www.debian-multimedia.org squeeze main
```

- Replace `squeeze` by `testing` or `unstable` or whatever distribution you follow.
- Remove `contrib` and `non-free` if you want to install free software exclusively.
- If you don't live in France, replace `ftp.fr.debian.org` by the name of another [Debian mirror](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list).
- The `deb` lines are for binary packages, the `deb-src` lines are for source packages. If you never want to download sources, you don't need the `deb-src` lines. If you do, you need a `deb-src` line to match each `deb` line.
- Only two sources are strictly necessary: the distribution proper (`protocol://mirror.example.com/debian release_name main`) and security updates (`deb http://security.debian.org/ release_name/updates`). Include the others only if you want them:

  - [stable-updates](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/release-notes/ch-whats-new.en.html#stable-updates) are updates of databases that need to be kept current, such as virus signature lists. Applies to the stable release only.
  - [Backports](http://www.backports.org/) are pacakges from unstable that are recompiled for stable. Even if you include this source, the packages will only be installed on explicit request: if a package also has a version outside backports, the non-backports version will be preferred even if it's older. Applies to the stable release only.
  - [Debian multimedia](http://www.debian-multimedia.org/) has packages that don't meet the legal requirements of the main distribution. They're mainly useful for desktop machines, to support more audio and video formats.

There are many other [unofficial repositories](http://www.apt-get.org/) if you're after a specific application.

Comment: you r awesome, gilles!!